# mobile app using google maps api, can use user api-key?

Tags: android, google-maps, google-cloud-platform

sorry im poor english.

I trying make an open-source mobile application using google maps api ( needed api key feature )

problem: i do not want pay by api usage from all user.

my solution: **application let do not have app-key, and user need setup ( input to app ) self-private-api-key.**

question: i know api-key can separate per domain ( server type application ), but **api-key can separate per end-user** ? ( by same mobile application, maybe same binary )

if it impossible, i need client app and "an api access server app", and user need deploy server app,,, it is too many cost, unreal ... orz

i could find some app required app key,but its server application. i couldnt find api-key required client application ( mobile application )

Comment: I just about assure you this would be against their terms of service.  They want to make money off that api, gathering the data wasn't cheap.

Comment: thanks, yea , i think so too (TT  , it is avoid paying.  but it mean anyone cannot make open-source app using maps api.  i think it questionable (TT